# Link Esri web map to XML data feed

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-portal

I have an XML feed of road conditions that needs to be linked to a roads layer in an Esri web map. The web map should be built with Portal for ArcGIS. (Though other suggestions/approaches are welcome!)

Can anyone provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

The XML data is:
http://hotline.gov.sk.ca/cgi-bin/atom/atom.py?key=92ddd862335b48e494c98f38249a0ee6

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `GeoEvent Extension for ArcGis Server` in order to use realtime data. You can find tutorials on how to use it over here:
http://server.arcgis.com/en/geoevent-extension/latest/get-started/what-is-arcgis-geoevent-extension-for-server.htm

I took a look at the xml-stream, but there is no geodata available. So you might want to use a geolocator too.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach would be to create a Hosted Feature Service of the roads and corresponding attributes in your portal. Then you can use the ArcGIS REST API to update the attributes. This could be automated with a python script that parses the XML feed and sends the updates on a regular interval.

To establish the initial Hosted Feature Service, you could use python to convert the XML feed to CSV and use the [Join Features](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/geoanalytics-join-features.htm) tool to associate the attributes with your road layer.

[Hosted Feature Service REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Update_Features/02r3000000zt000000/)

[Python Notebook Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/updating-features-in-a-feature-layer/)